# How to hide button functionality programatically?

Tags: android

When i click a button1 from **one screen(Activity1)**, iam displaying a **another screen(Calling an Activity2)** which has a HeaderName and some UI elements with their click events.

If i click button2, I want to display the same screen with different HeaderName and different click events of the same UI elements.

I mean when i click 6 buttons(from Activity1), i want same screen with different Header and different functionalities.

Iam very new to this, How to do this?

please help

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you want a bit more clearly?

Comment: HeaderName is TextView? If so you can use `setText` on each onClick and change the Header.

Comment: pass the info along with intent and make necessary changes on activity two as per intent extra data from activity one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by various ways

1.Using [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

In this case you don't have to show second activity on click of button1 in Activity1.

Instead, use fragment in Activity1 where all buttons will be placed. When you will click button say button1 you will show (or replace current fragment) fragment related to that button as shown below.

```
   FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
   transaction.addToBackStack("fragment2");
   transaction.commit();
```

Here make note that transaction has addToBackStack() method which will be helpful in going back to initial fragment (which contains all buttons)

2.Using Activities

In this case you will send flag/integer value with Activity to start second activity

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("option",1); // for button1 click
  startActivity(intent);
```

In SecondActivity, use getExtra() to get this integer

```
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  int option = extras.getInt("option");
```

Now you have information about which button clicked in Activity1. Use this value to populate UI accordingly

If you are using HeaderName in ActionBar then in both cases you can change ActionBar title accordingly

Comment: perfect with second option, as iam new to Fragment concept. Thanks :)

Comment: That's good. but try to learn Fragment. In future, you will need it for complex applications :)